# How to set socket option (IP_TOS) for http client in go language?

Tags: http, ssl, go

I am a newbie to go language. I plan to use go language for developing an http client/Server. 
While browsing through the list of features supported in http client package I do not find a way to set socket option in the package 
(May be I just do not know how to use it). I am in a need to set DSCP option (IP_TOS) in the fd before calling http client connection. 
(Although I find syscall option to set socket options, I do not find a way to get fd from http package).

**In http server side**, able to set socket option (IP_TOS).
code excerpt:

```
       tcpListener,err := net.ListenTCP("tcp4", addr)
        if  err != nil {
             //fmt.Println("error in listen", err.error())
             log.Fatal("net.ListenTCP()", err)
        }
        //get lisenet socket fd
        f, _ := tcpListener.File()
        err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(f.Fd()), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.IP_TOS, 128)
```

**In http client side,** **not able to get socket fd and set socket option** (IP_TOS):
(I want to set IP_TOS before calling NewRequest)

```
     client := &http.Client{
                         Transport : tr,
                         //Timeout: time.Duration(10) * time.Second,
       }

     request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)
       if err != nil {
           panic(err)
       }

      response, err := client.Do(request)
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own `DialContext` for your own `http.RoundTripper` of your own `*http.Client`:

```
dial := func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }).DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    tcpConn, ok := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
    if !ok {
        err = errors.New("conn is not tcp")
        return nil, err
    }

    f, err := tcpConn.File()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(f.Fd()), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_TOS, 128)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}
tr := &http.Transport{
    Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext:           dial,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}
c := &http.Client{
    Transport: tr,
}
resp, err := c.Get("https://google.com/")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("GET error: %v", err)
}

log.Printf("got %q", resp.Status)
```

---

**EDIT:** If you need to set the option *before* the connection actually happens, you can try this in your `DialContext`, but this is fairly non-portable, unsafe, doesn't account for context, and will probably break sooner or later:

```
tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr(network, addr)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

sa := &syscall.SockaddrInet4{
    Port: tcpAddr.Port,
    Addr: [4]byte{tcpAddr.IP[0], tcpAddr.IP[1], tcpAddr.IP[2], tcpAddr.IP[3]},
}

fd, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_TOS, 128)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = syscall.Connect(fd, sa)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

file := os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), "")
conn, err := net.FileConn(file)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return conn, nil
```

---

**EDIT 2:** In Go 1.11 you'll be able to do this:

```
dialer := &net.Dialer{
    Control: func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
        return c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
            err := syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_TOS, 128)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("control: %s", err)
                return
            }
        })
    },
}
// ...
tr := &http.Transport{
    Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext:           dialer.DialContext,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for your detailed response. I have tested above code through sample program But socket option IP_TOS value couldn't set in syn packet initiated from http client. Here I have one doubt , while passing argument to DialContext( ctx, network, addr), how to create context to pass as ctx. Currently I used  **DialContext(context.Background() network, addr)** ?

Comment: @ManojSaha See edit and try it. Whether it works or not, you might want to request a feature on the Go issue tracker to somehow allow setting options on FDs.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts!! I tested in sample program , set api for dscp setting is success and I could read the dscp value through get api for dscp, but it's not reflecting in the tcp connection request in syn packet. still I am seeing dscp is 0.

Comment: Same here. Used `SetsockoptInt` on a `TCPConn` directly and saw `dscp=0` on wireshark. Go 1.10 on MacOS 10.13

Comment: @PedroA.Aranda @manoj-saha Two years later I have finally found the mistake. I should've been using `syscall.IPPROTO_IP` instead of `syscall.SOL_SOCKET` all this time. See my last edit. I've checked in in Wireshark, and I'm getting non-zero DSCP.